# Haskell Filter list by custom tuple

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function to filter my list of custom tuples in the form ((d1,d2),d3) by the a parameter value larger than d3.

filterTuple 1.5 [((1.0,2.0),1.0),((3.0,5.0),2.0),((4.0,5.0),2.0)] should return [((3.0,5.0),2.0),((4.0,5.0),2.0)]

```
filterTuples :: Double ->[((Double, Double), Double)] -> [((Double, Double), Double)] 
filterTuples val [((d1,d2),d3)] = filter (d3 < val) [((d1,d2),d3)]
```

This throws the error below with the expression in `d3 < val`, what is correct to write in there instead?

```
x8.hs:54:47: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘((Double, Double), Double) -> Bool’
              with actual type ‘Bool’
• Possible cause: ‘(<)’ is applied to too many arguments
  In the first argument of ‘filter’, namely ‘(d3 < value)’
  In the expression: filter (d3 < value) [((d1, d2), d3)]
  In an equation for ‘filterTuples’:
      filterTuples value [((d1, d2), d3)]
        = filter (d3 < value) [((d1, d2), d3)]    |
```

Comment: What should `filter (d3 < val) [((d1,d2),d3)]` do?

Comment: It should return a list [((d1,d2),d3)] of all d3 that are less than the value

Comment: but your pattern only matches lists with **one** element.

Comment: How would I rewrite it to match lists in the format?

Comment: the signature of the function already does that. But you need a function to pass to the `filter`.

Comment: Do you mean like this `filter (((_,_),d3) <epsilon) [((d1,d2),d3)]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you here have written is pattern matching that *only* matches a **list with one element**. You write:

```
filterTuples val [((d1,d2),d3)] = ...
```

So this means a list with *one* element: a tuple `((d1,d2),d3)`. This is *not* how you should filter lists an arbitrary number of elements.

We can write it as `l`:

```
filterTuples val l = ...
```

but now we of course still have to write a `filter`. The **`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`** function expects a function `a -> Bool` as parameter that is a predicate that should decide what elements to keep.

We thus have to design such function. We can write this as a *lambda expression*:

```
\((d1,d2),d3) -> d3 < val
```

So now we can write it as:

```
filterTuples :: Ord a => a -> [((b,c),a)] -> [((b,c),a)]
filterTuples val l = filter (\((d1,d2),d3) -> d3 < val) l
```

Now we can still improve it. For instance we can perform an *eta reduction*: eliminate the variable both in the head and body of the clause:

```
filterTuples :: Ord a => a -> [((b,c),a)] -> [((b,c),a)]
filterTuples val = filter (\((d1,d2),d3) -> d3 < val)
```

Still we can improve it. For instance it is not clear why you want to filter only tuples with a tuple as first element. Why not generalize it to all possible 2-tuples?

```
filterTuples :: Ord a => a -> [(d,a)] -> [(d,a)]
filterTuples val = filter (\(dx,d3) -> d3 < val)
```

We also usually write variables we do not care about with an underscore (`_`):

```
filterTuples :: Ord a => a -> [(d,a)] -> [(d,a)]
filterTuples val = filter (\(_,d3) -> d3 < val)
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes far more sense now. However when I try to execute this it won't compile.

Comment: I get the error `ex8.hs:54:1: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[((b, c), a)]’
                  with actual type ‘[((a0, b0), [((b, c), a)])]
                                    -> [((a0, b0), [((b, c), a)])]’
    • The equation(s) for ‘filterTuples’ have two arguments,
      but its type ‘[((b, c), a)] -> [((b, c), a)]’ has only one
    • Relevant bindings include
        filterTuples :: [((b, c), a)] -> [((b, c), a)]
          (bound at ex8.hs:54:1)
   |
54 | filterTuples val l = filter (\((d1,d2),d3) -> d3 < val) l`